# pod creation stuck in pending status for hours

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc, eksctl

This is my eksctl command to create a EKS cluster:

```
eksctl create cluster \
--name app \
--version 1.29 \
--region us-east-1 \
--nodegroup-name app-worker-group \
--node-type t2.micro \
--nodes 1 \
--vpc-cidr 172.31.0.0/16
```

After creation, I deploy a deployment like so:

```
kubectl apply -f k8s/deployment.yaml
```

Where the yaml file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-api
  labels:
    app: app-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app-api
          image: path/to/image
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2201 # port of the node js app
```

But the pod status is perpetually pending:

```
~/Documents/app kubectl get pod
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
app-api-785cbb9d89-vvbdf   0/1     Pending   0          11h
```

What could be the reason for this?

EDITED:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  2m1s (x4 over 17m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Too many pods. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
```

Comment: this occurs usually because either no toleration  with nodes' taints or there's insufficient CPU or memory in your node, use kubectl describe pod  app-api-785cbb9d89-vvbdf for details

Comment: I have added the output of your command. It says too many pods. But there is only one?

Comment: the only node that is running I think it has no resource limits, hence the pod may reserved most of node resources and caused resource lack, describe the node you have and check of percentage  of CPU and MEMORY usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...0/1 nodes are available: 1 Too many pods

Your cluster currently only has 1 node and the current running number of pods on this node `--node-type t2.micro` cannot run any more pods. You can add 1 more node to your cluster on the AWS Console > EKS > Compute (tab) > Node groups, goto the node group and click "Edit" to increase the "Desired size".